# how to get rid of duplicate lette in wordle

Tags: python

so I created this wordle version
one things that triggers me is for example the secret word is 'brawl'
and if I guessed hello for example the two L will be in yellow but the case is one only should be in yellow and the other in grey.

#class to verify that the player print word contain 5 letter and exist in english

#the main function to check if the player guessed the word if the letter in right position we colored it to green if the letter in the secret word but not in the right postion we color it to yellow else color it to grey

```
from collections import Counter
import sys
from termcolor import colored, cprint
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
from colored import fg, bg, attr
import time
from random import choice

#class to verify that the player print word contain 5 letter and exist in english
class Player():  
    @staticmethod
    def read_content(value):
        with open('words.txt','r') as f:
            contents=f.read()
            if value.lower() in contents:
                return True
            else:
                return False
    
    
    def check_word(self):
        valid_word=False
        while not valid_word:
            val=input()
            if len(val)>5:
                print("You have given a word that exceeds 5 letters")
                continue
            elif len(val)<5:
                print("You have given a word less than 5 letters")
                continue
            elif len(val)==5 and not self.read_content(val):
                print("you give a word with 5 letter that doesn't exist in dictionnary")
            elif len(val)==5 and self.read_content(val):
                return val
                valid_word=True

#class of the game to read to select random word from a file txt and the rules of the game
class Wordle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.word=self.today_word()
        
    @staticmethod
    def today_word():
        with open('words.txt','r') as f:
            contents=f.readlines()
        return choice(contents)
    @staticmethod
    def game_rules():
        print("\tYou have five attempts to guess today word\n")
        print(f"when the color is {colored('GREEN','green',attrs=['bold'])} that means the letter in the right postion\n"
          +f"when the color is {colored('YELLOW','yellow',attrs=['bold'])} that means the letter is in the wrong position\n"
          +f"when the color is {colored('GREY','grey',attrs=['bold'])} that means the letter doesn't exist in the word")
        print("please print the word that's in your mind")




def play_wordle(game,player):
    game.game_rules()
    todays_word=game.word
    attempt=1
    while attempt<6:
        player_word=player.check_word()
        for index,letter in enumerate(player_word):
            if player_word[index] == todays_word[index]:
                print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_green',attrs=['bold']),end='')
                print('  ',end='')
            elif letter in todays_word:
                print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_yellow',attrs=['bold']),end='')
                print('  ',end='')
            else:
                print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_grey',attrs=['bold']),end='')
                print('  ',end='')
            time.sleep(0.8)
        if player_word != todays_word:
            attempt=attempt+1
        elif player_word == todays_word:
            print(f"\nCongratulation you've guessed the word of today:{game.word} ")
            break
    if player_word != todays_word:
        print(f"\nSorry you lost today's word is :{todays_word.upper()}")
```

Comment: You can feed user input in a "collections.Counter", use it to check for yellow letter and subtract each shown letter (especially if green or yellow) from it.

Comment: can you explain more i didn't quiet understand how to implement that in my code

Comment: I wrote an answer. In my comment I wrote that user input should be fed in a Counter which is wrong. The "todays_word" must be fed instead.

Comment: I test that but it doesnt work.
for example the word of today is' bawls' when I enter: 'hello' the first L is yellow the second L is green but what I want is the first L should be grey and the the second L is green because its in the right postion

Comment: I have rewritten my answer so that it should now process the coloring correctly. The non-stopping while-loop shouldn't be caused by my code.

Comment: thanks man.It worked 
Man I wish I can think of that like you did.

Answer (score 0):

When importing `Counter` with

```
from collections import Counter
```

The for-loop to color the letters must be rewritten as two loops to process positional matches before the rest:

```
    tw_count = Counter(todays_word)
    greens = [False] * len(player_word)
    
    for index,letter in enumerate(player_word):
        if player_word[index] == todays_word[index]:
            greens[index] = True
            tw_count.subtract((letter,))
            
    for index,letter in enumerate(player_word):
        if greens[index]:
            print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_green',attrs=['bold']),end='')
            print('  ',end='')
        elif tw_count[letter] > 0:
            print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_yellow',attrs=['bold']),end='')
            print('  ',end='')
            tw_count.subtract((letter,))
        else:
            print(colored(letter.upper(),'red','on_grey',attrs=['bold']),end='')
            print('  ',end='')
            tw_count.subtract((letter,))
        
        time.sleep(0.8)
```

Comment: thanks man.It worked
Man I wish I can think of that like you did.